# cronjob is running 2x in a hour instead 1x

Tags: cron, debian-squeeze

I have written a small backup script for my vserver and added its execution to my /etc/crontab

```
25 * * * * root /etc/cron.daily/backup.sh
```

This is the entry (yeah it is still located in the wrong folder right now :) )
But when I check my log I see that the script is executed a min of 2 times a hour. Which is not a problem but I would like to know why this is happening.

```
Backup done on Fr 8. Jun 02:59:00 UTC 2012
Backup done on Fr 8. Jun 03:28:20 UTC 2012
Backup done on Fr 8. Jun 03:58:44 UTC 2012
Backup done on Fr 8. Jun 04:39:44 UTC 2012
Backup done on Fr 8. Jun 05:06:43 UTC 2012
Backup done on Fr 8. Jun 05:32:34 UTC 2012
Backup done on Fr 8. Jun 05:59:06 UTC 2012
Backup done on Fr 8. Jun 06:28:58 UTC 2012
Backup done on Fr 8. Jun 06:59:07 UTC 2012
```

Comment: What's in `/etc/cron.d` `/etc/crontab` and `/etc/cron.hourly` ?

Comment: in cron.d is only a script for removing old php sessions, for testing I removed my script from /etc/crontab and put it in /etc/cron.hourly but it is not executed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scripts in `/etc/cron.daily` are automatically run daily, scripts in `/etc/cron.hourly` hourly. There is no need to put a script into one of the `/etc/cron.{hourly|daily|weekly|monthly}` AND calling it from `/etc/crontab`. Putting your script into `/etc/cron.hourly` and calling it from `/etc/crontab` would run the script twice.

I suggest you also add a `Backup started` log message. That way you will see when it gets called any you can eventually correlate that information with what you have configured.

Comment: Ok I tried it you way but when I just put my script into cron.hourly it never gonna executed that's why I added it manually to /etc/crontab

Comment: For `cron.hourly` to work, you need a line such as `17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly` in `/etc/crontab`. Do you have that line?

Comment: yep exactly that line

Comment: And your `/etc/cron.hourly/backup.sh` is executable? Then it should definitely work. You can also enter `cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly` on the command line to see what happens. Maybe you will get an error message that tells you why the script isn't run.

Comment: yeah it is executable but even if I run the command manually it is not executed.

Comment: Try to add `--verbose` to `run-parts`. See `man run-parts`...

Comment: Ok the problem was that my script filename contained a . This is not allowed by run-parts